# Emit a response with PSR-7

Tags: php, psr-7

I'm trying to understand how PSR-7 works and I get stuck! Here is my code:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    $stream = new Stream('php://memory', 'rw');
    $stream->write('Foo');
    $response = (new Response())
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        ->withBody($stream);
});
```

My Response object is build but now I want to send it...
How PSR-7 send response? Do I need serialization? I probably missed one thing...

Comment: Which framework you plan to use ?

You can take a look at their example, on how they utilize the PSR-7. For example Slim framework https://www.slimframework.com/

Answer (score 9):

Just as a completion, even if the question is more than two years old:

A response is a HTTP message sent by a server to a client, as result of a request from the client to the server.

The client expects a string as message, composed of:

- a "**status line**" (in the form `HTTP/<protocol-version> <status-code> <reason-phrase>`);
- a list of **headers** (each in the form "`<header-name>: <comma-separ.-header-values>`");
- an empty line;
- a **message body** (a string).

And it looks like this (see [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
vary: Accept-Encoding

This is the response body
```

In order to emit a response, one must actually perform three operations:

1. **Send** the "status line" to the client (using the [**header()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) PHP function).
2. **Send** the headers list to the client (*dito*).
3. **Output** the message body.

The tricky part is represented by the third operation. An instance of a class implementing the `ResponseInterface` contains a stream object as the message body. And this object must be converted to a string and printed. The task can be easily accomplished, because the stream is an instance of a class implementing `StreamInterface`, which, in turn, enforces the definition of a magical method [**__toString()**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring).

So, by performing the first two steps and applying an output function (`echo`, `print_r`, etc) to the result of the `getBody()` method of the response instance, the emitting process is complete.

```
<?php
if (headers_sent()) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Headers were already sent. The response could not be emitted!');
}

// Step 1: Send the "status line".
$statusLine = sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s'
        , $response->getProtocolVersion()
        , $response->getStatusCode()
        , $response->getReasonPhrase()
);
header($statusLine, TRUE); /* The header replaces a previous similar header. */

// Step 2: Send the response headers from the headers list.
foreach ($response->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
    $responseHeader = sprintf('%s: %s'
            , $name
            , $response->getHeaderLine($name)
    );
    header($responseHeader, FALSE); /* The header doesn't replace a previous similar header. */
}

// Step 3: Output the message body.
echo $response->getBody();
exit();
```

P.S: For large amounts of data it's better to use the `php://temp` stream instead of `php://memory`. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory) is the reason.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Sending HTTP response in pure PHP. I've enclosed your code in function `function sendResponse(Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response)` and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Psr-7 just models http messages. It does not have functionalities to send responses. You need to use another library that consumes PSR-7 messages. You could have a look at [zend stratigility](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility) or something of the like

Comment: What I concluced to is to use zend diactoros' SapiEmitter:
```
$emitter = new \Zend\Diactoros\Response\SapiEmitter();
$emitter->emit(new Response(…));
```
that's all you need then.